# Wavefront obj loader with material files for c/cpp

Tags: c++, opengl, wavefront

I am looking for a wavefront obj loader which supports loading material properties files.

Basically supporing the [minimum standard](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/minobj.html).

In addition I am using math glm library for my vectors and matrices and I am looking for something that integrates well this this.

Searching for options I have found another library called [glm](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/) (confusing??) which so far looks like the best alternative, although this has much more then I need, I only want the loaders not a set of rendering options included.

Other options i have looked at so far:
- assimp, very extensive, much more then I need

- libwave, from 1996 and wants do to rendering
- libobj, looks promising but does not support material yet.
- Libobj, maybe a good alternative, looks like it supports what I need, but it is lacking some  basic examples and needs some work for me to integrate it with the rest of my code.
- libwavefront does not support material files

Are there any other modern options which could fit in my project?

Comment: Just go with assimp. If you'll ever need to load another model, the time invested in assimp will be well spent. The alternative, if you are _really_ keen on keeping things lean and mean and doing nothing more than your exact specification: write your own loader. It's rather trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing your own will take about one day and you will be able to add and remove features! It's not very hard and there are plenty of tutorials. I recommend this one:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=849hXuOv0i8

Comment: I've tried his code and it's outdated/doesn't work well with Visual Studio

Comment: Look at the code, he is only reading from a file in a particular way. It is the same as loading an XML file really. The OpenGL might be a tad depreciated just use that code as a base and modify. Also he writes in a very C way, might be of use to you to try it more OO